# WPF datagrid column width codebehind 30*

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn

i'd like to set the width of my datagrid column and my desired value is 30*.

I found this

```
 var columntu = new ExtDataGridNumericColumn()
{
    Tag = tagName,
    Header = header,
    Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto)
};
```

but I can only set

```
public enum DataGridLengthUnitType
{
    Auto = 0,
    Pixel = 1,
    SizeToCells = 2,
    SizeToHeader = 3,
    Star = 4,
}
```

How can I set 30* as width of my column?
Thank you
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`30*` in XAML is `new DataGridLength(30, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star)` in C#:

```
columntu.Width = new DataGridLength(30, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```